# How to read this XML file in C++? non standard (read) "INVALID" XML

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

So I came across this XML file I want to read in C++. It seems pretty strange in its header information and there's lots of files like this. I cant seem to make a change in bulk so I am going to have to read it as it is.

I'm also open to parsing it by directly using ifstream. I want to extract the data and the numbers. The content of one of the files are as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE refSeg SYSTEM "isthisthereallife.no">
<refSeg src="skjkska.doc" how="dunno" willa="25820">
<trans type="IN1" pum1="2280" pum2="2281"/>
<trans type="IN2" pum1="3495" pum2="3496"/>
<trans type="IN3" pum1="4936" pum2="4937"/>
</refSeg>
```

I want the numbers under "pum1" and "pum2" in separate variables / matrix format / list. And also the "type" in another variable.

Comment: If by "non-standard" you mean "invalid", then you're going to struggle with 3rd-party XML libraries - they're usually designed to tolerate only valid XML.  You could either write your own parser (don't!) or perform the necessary surgery to convert the data to valid XML first.

Comment: But I have so many files, is there no way to read this data via ifstream directly?

Comment: You can read it via any standard mechanism.  But it's the XML parsing that will be the problem.

Comment: Also how can I convert this data into valid XML?

Comment: Is all the `XML` this simple format?

Comment: I see no reason to parse this file as `XML`. Just treat it like text (which is what it is) and write the simplest text parser that will get the job done.

Comment: What's the problem with parsing the file as XML exactly? That there is a DOCTYPE declaration and your XML parsing lib can't deal with it or  that it can't find the `isthisthereallife.no` DTD file it references?

Comment: Okay give me an approach to parsing it as an XML in C++

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing everyone by talking about "non standard" and "invalid" XML.

There's nothing "non standard" about the XML sample you've shown us. We can't tell whether it's "invalid" - that all depends on the DTD definitions in the file "isthisthereallife.no", which define what elements and attributes the XML file is allowed to contain.

I suspect when you say "non standard" you mean "I've never seen an XML file with a DOCTYPE definition before".

Your next step depends on whether you can locate the DTD file "isthisthereallife.no", and if you can, on what it says about the permitted XML content.

As a general tip for asking SO questions, if something isn't working you should tell us exactly what you did and exactly how it fails.

Comment: Well, it wasn't my suggestion that you change the post, so please don't blame me. If you did listen, you would have read my suggestion, which is that before we can tell you how to parse the file, we need to know whether the DTD file exists, and if so, what's in it.